# IsTag() only returns true for a couple of the many frames rendered while an animation with that tag is running

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am trying to check if an animation (started by using SetTrigger("") is still running or has finished. Each of these animations have the tag "Attack", but running

```
animatorReference.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsTag("Attack")
```

returns true only once for a brief moment during the whole time the animation is playing (it returns false the rest of the time), and at the end of the animation. Does the IsTag() function just not work or am I majorly overlooking something?

I have tried changing the name of the tag as well as manually hashing the string "attack", but it still only returns a hash of "attack"/only returns true once each time an animation is run, at the end of the animation.

Comment: Is it heavily blended?

Comment: @BugFinder I think this may be the solution, thank you! I had not changed the blending at all for the transition to the attack animations, but I had removed all blending for the transition away from the attack animtions. Removing the blending on the transitions to the attack animations appears to have fixed it.

Comment: @BugFinder if you want to write this as the answer, I would gladly mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I had not tested it directly it is logical (and you proved me right) that if an animation is having a transition and blending 2 animations together it is not necessary going to be under the name of the one animation. Nor is the animation going to make it to 100% because it will have transitioned onto the next by then.